# free() and struct in C

Tags: c

How to deallocate memory for the following code: I want to store names in name field of the given below structure struct tag and then deallocate the memory

```
SINT32 TestExample(void)
{
    typedef struct tag
    {
        char *name;
    } ST;

    int i;
    ST **p, **p1;
    p = p1 = (ST **)calloc(1, 10 * sizeof(ST *));

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        p[0] = (ST *)calloc(1, 10 * sizeof(ST));
        p[0]->name = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

        sprintf(p[0]->name, "Name_%d", i);

        ++p;
    }

    /* TO DO: free the memory allocated in previous block */
    {
        ------------------------
    }

    p = NULL:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You also need to free memory within the for loop scope. Your nominated position is insufficient.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to both increase `i` and `p` at the same time in your p[i] indexing loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should free `name` before freeing the struct.

```
p = p1;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    free(p[i]->name);
    free(p[i]);
}
free(p1);
```

The basic idea is that you should free the things you allocate memory to, in an order that allows you to free the other things.

You also need to "reset" the pointer `p` to the original address by doing `p = p1;`

Comment: thanks for the comment. Your code above is working fine wihout memory leaks only if p is replaced by p1. I am not able to understand..

Comment: I just realized that you need to "reset" the pointer `p`, since you modified it with `++p`.  My edit should work now.

Comment: thanks for the help..the code is leak free with :                             

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        free(p1[i]->name);
        free(p1[i]);
        p++;                                                           
        }free(p1)

Comment: You are welcome! (also, just realized that the `p++` isn't necessary)

Answer (score 2):

Call `free(object)` on the same objects you called `malloc` on in a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

as you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) by doing

```
free(p);
```

be careful not to free memory that wasn't allocated, so you won't get debug assertion failed.

Comment: free(p) is not working. It is saying debug assertion failed on visual studio. However free(p1[i]) is working but all the memory are not freed

Comment: @user2656773 you are freeing  memory that was not allocated